# regex split with exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This is an extension to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419803/regex-net-split). This question considers two different enclosing characters, in contrast to the original question.

I would like to split by (white)spaces of any number but ignore everything between <> AND "". So this string:

```
string Line = "1  2  <1  2> \"hello world\"   3";
```

Should result in this:

1, 2, <1 2>, \"hello world\", 3

Comment: If you're ignoring anything between <> and "" shouldn't the result be `1, 2, <1  2>, \"hello world\", 3` (note the 2 whitespaces between `<1` and `2>`)

Comment: The number of whitespaces should not matter and nothing should be split if it is enclosed by "" or <>.

Comment: @dan1111. It is definitely not a duplicate!

Comment: @csetzkorn how the heck is that not a duplicate? Because they used square brackets instead of quotes?

Comment: Yes, the 'answer' which you may refer to uses [. My original question asks explicitly about ONE exception rather than 2 as in THIS question.

Comment: I have voted for reopening, but you should edit the question and say exactly what behaviour do you wand for the case if intersection of <> and "" areas. For now it seems that you don't realise what you want exactly. Now the question is not well understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with so far:

```
public static string[] GetSplitStrings(string input)
{
    IList<string> splitStrings = new List<string>();
    var counter = 0;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var inLessGreater = false; // sometimes <> can contain "
    foreach (var character in input)
    {
    if (character.Equals('<'))
    {
        inLessGreater = true;
        counter++;
    }

    if (character.Equals('>'))
    {
        inLessGreater = false;
        counter++;
    }

    if (character.Equals('"') && !inLessGreater)
    {
        counter++;
    }

    if ((character.Equals(' ') && counter == 0) || (counter == 2))
    {
        if (sb.ToString().Equals("") == false)
        {
        if (character.Equals('"') || character.Equals('>'))
        {
            sb.Append(character);
        }
        splitStrings.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
        sb.Clear();
        counter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(character);
    }
    }

    return splitStrings.ToArray();
}
```

Would prefer a neat regex solution.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `Split`, I'll use `Matches`

```
string Line = "1  2  <1  2> \"hello world\"   3";
var parts = Regex.Matches(Line, @"[<\""]{1}[\w \d]+?[>\""]{1}|[\w\d]+")
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(m=>m.Value)
                 .ToArray();
```

PS: This would also match `"abc def>`. But I ignored it to make the regex shorter

Comment: Excellent, however it does not seem to work for "" (e.g. ""  1 2 -> "",1,2)